# How To Increase Countdown With Input Well Running?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to restart the setInterval for only -1 second every time I click insert any idea? how to  make it restart and increase my value well running? For example clear the setInterval -1 second session from **tick( )** and start a new -1 second session so the tick() wont keep looping the function every time I click it

```js
var timeInSecs;
var ticker;

function startTimer() {
  var newValues = document.getElementById("mm").value;
  var secondInput = document.getElementById("secondsdown").value;
  if (secondInput == null || secondInput == '') {
    secondInput = '0';
  } else {
    secondInput = document.getElementById("secondsdown").value;
  }
  var secs = 60 * parseInt(newValues);

  timeInSecs = parseInt(secs + parseInt(secondInput));
  ticker = setInterval("tick()", 1000);
}

function tick() {
  var secs = timeInSecs;
  document.getElementById("secondsdown").value = secs;
  if (secs > 0) {
    timeInSecs--;
  } else {
    clearInterval(ticker);
  }
  var days = Math.floor(secs / 86400);
  secs %= 86400;
  var hours = Math.floor(secs / 3600);
  secs %= 3600;
  var mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
  secs %= 60;
  var pretty = ((hours < 10) ? "0" : "") + hours + ":" + ((mins < 10) ? "0" : "") + mins + ":" + ((secs < 10) ? "0" : "") + secs;
  document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = pretty;
}
```

```html
<div class="master-slider ms-skin-light-2" id="masterslider">
<div class="ms-slide">

<input type="number" id="secondsdown"/>
<span id="countdown"></span>
<input id="mm" placeholder="分钟" type="number";/>
<input type="button" value="Click" onclick="startTimer()"/>
</div>
</div><!-- end of masterslider1 -->
```

I understand this line cause the issues but how to stop it increase from i++

```
ticker = setInterval(tick, 1000);
```

Comment: you can use clearTimeout. 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearTimeout

Comment: Indentation makes a big difference in making your code more readable, any chance you can [edit] your question? Also, why not use `setInterval( tick, 1000 )`?

Comment: sry @Icepickle is my first time start a question in stackoverflow

Comment: Never **eval functions** inside setTimeout / interval s. `setInterval("tick()", 1000)` should be `setInterval(tick, 1000)`. Also, don't use inline `on*` handlers in HTML. JS should be in one place only. Use addEventListener() instead.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on how you look at it :) You've started alright, but the problem is your `startTimer()`, where upon every click, you always start a new interval.

This shouldn't really be necessary, so either:

- always clear the interval before starting a new interval
- only start the interval if no interval was active yet

As I'm not sure what your goal is, the easiest change was to consecutively call `clearInterval` and `setInterval`.

The only other thing I've changed, is to call `tick()` once inside the `startTimer` so that the user doesn't have to wait 1 second before a reaction comes from the UI ( which is a bit confusing :) )

```js
var timeInSecs;
var ticker;

function startTimer() {
  var newValues = document.getElementById("mm").value;
  var secondInput = document.getElementById("secondsdown").value;
  if (secondInput == null || secondInput == '') {
    secondInput = '0';
  } else {
    secondInput = document.getElementById("secondsdown").value;
  }
  var secs = 60 * parseInt(newValues);

  timeInSecs = parseInt(secs + parseInt(secondInput));
  tick();
  // clear any previous timers
  clearInterval( ticker );
  // start new timer
  ticker = setInterval(tick, 1000);
}

function tick() {
  var secs = timeInSecs;
  document.getElementById("secondsdown").value = secs;
  if (secs > 0) {
    timeInSecs--;
  } else {
    clearInterval(ticker);
  }
  var days = Math.floor(secs / 86400);
  secs %= 86400;
  var hours = Math.floor(secs / 3600);
  secs %= 3600;
  var mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
  secs %= 60;
  var pretty = ((hours < 10) ? "0" : "") + hours + ":" + ((mins < 10) ? "0" : "") + mins + ":" + ((secs < 10) ? "0" : "") + secs;
  document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = pretty;
}
```

```html
<div class="master-slider ms-skin-light-2" id="masterslider">
<div class="ms-slide">

<input type="number" id="secondsdown"/>
<span id="countdown"></span>
<input id="mm" placeholder="分钟" type="number";/>
<input type="button" value="Click" onclick="startTimer()"/>
</div>
</div><!-- end of masterslider1 -->
```

Comment: ya i figurate out also thanks for the fully details :>